# Blogdown External URLs

Tags: r, markdown, blogdown

I am familiar with Blogdown but am hitting a bit of a wall with an inline url. Below is the typical url invocation for Blogdown.

```
[linked phrase]("http://example.com")
```

But when I click the link I get:

```
Not found:
./Semantic/"http://example.com"
```

The name of my page is `/Semantic/` so the URL is being prefaced with the page name as if it is an internal link between pages.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the URL.

```
[Rand Fishkin’s](https://moz.com/blog/lda-and-googles-rankings-well-correlated)
```

Please at least learn [the basic syntax of Markdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-syntax.html). If you are serious about Markdown, I strongly recommend that you [read the full Pandoc manual](https://yihui.name/en/2017/11/thanks-tj-mahr/).

Comment: Thanks @Yihui Xie. Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem! It was in quotes. Hope this helps someone else!